# Value for EXCLUDE is badly formed Importing Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, datapump, impdp, imp

I want to import a `Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production`

using the command :

```
impdp SOLVIA/SOLVIA900@IMMBO DIRECTORY=DB_EXP DUMPFILE=week_exp_immbo.dmp LOGFILE=week_exp_immbo.log REUSE_DATAFILES=YES exclude=tablespace:"IN ('IMMBO')"
```

But I got this error:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-39071: Value for EXCLUDE is badly formed.
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

Comment: Hi, I  assume your Oracle database is on a Linux server.  Can you confirm?

Comment: nop, no a windows server 12 r2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Exclude Arguments with Data Pump in Command Mode Require Quotations to be Escaped**

The invocation you are using looks reasonable.

Here it is:

```
impdp SOLVIA/SOLVIA900@IMMBO DIRECTORY=DB_EXP DUMPFILE=week_exp_immbo.dmp LOGFILE=week_exp_immbo.log REUSE_DATAFILES=YES exclude=tablespace:"IN ('IMMBO')"
```

Per My Oracle Support document, [How To Resolve The Error ORA-39071 Value For EXCLUDE Is Badly Formed (Doc ID 734324.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/SearchDocDisplay?_adf.ctrl-state=bwbsee009_9&_afrLoop=207812775086251), you need to *escape the quotations like this:

```
impdp SOLVIA/SOLVIA900@IMMBO DIRECTORY=DB_EXP DUMPFILE=week_exp_immbo.dmp LOGFILE=week_exp_immbo.log REUSE_DATAFILES=YES exclude=tablespace:\"IN (\'IMMBO\')\"
```

<sub>*: Escaping quotation marks is required with a Linux operating system. This does not apply to Windows operating systems.</sub>